# Surface Pro: Outlook 2013 unable to connect to Exchange 2010

Tags: windows-8, exchange-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-surface

I've installed Office 2013 (via one of my 5 installation of office365 home premium) on my Surface Pro 128GB.

I can't connect to Exchange 2010 to read emails via Outlook 2013. I keep receiving this message:

> The name cannot be resolved. The Connection to microsoft Exchange is
>   unavailable. Outlook must be online or connected to complete this
>   action.

Any ideas?

*I have already a thread (where we checked DNS issues but that was or isn't the problem.)
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_365hp-outlook/surface-pro-outlook-2013-unable-to-connect-to/27865698-c0dd-439e-a524-99715a9b08e0 
I hope somebody here has some other tricks that I could try.*

**Update:**

I've tried this now: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2264398 but it didn't work.
any other ideas?

Comment: Is the device in the same windows-domain as the exchange-server?

Comment: Yes, the only think I could say is that when entering the device into the domain the first time it didn't work. 
I'm not sure if I added it via  COMPANY.LOCAL or via COMPANY.LOCAL. (see the dot '.' at the end)
But if I check the domain it is correct, I also see it in my AD.